# Get single row from either of two tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, select, union

I have a single login page for admins and users. They both use the same form and it has the fields email and password.

The database tables are the same except the admins table is called `admins` and the users is called `users`. The email field is unique to both so for example, if email "test@example.com" is in the `users` table, it will not be in the `admins` table.

What is the best way to get the row from both tables, return that row, and check which table it got it from?

Union, join, 2 `SELECT` queries, or maybe something else that can perform faster and more efficient?

```
SELECT * FROM admins
UNION
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE email = :email
```

or maybe two selects:

```
$row = SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1
if(!$row) {
    $row = SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1
}

// Then I want to do redirect them according to what type of user they are:
if(row comes from admins table) {
    header('Location: /admins');
} else {
    header('Location: /users');
}
```

Maybe some other way?

Comment: Normally you'd have a `user` table and a `role` table (and a link table of course) - stick all the users (and admins) in the `user` table then cross reference them to their role to see what they're allowed to do...

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should be having a single table for user information and add a role table to distinguish between admin and normal users. but if you can't do this, there is one solution.

```
 SELECT a.* , 'admin' as role FROM admins a
 UNION
 SELECT u.* , 'user' as role FROM users u
 WHERE email = 'abc@email.com'
```

'Role' column will tell you from which table you are getting the value.

Answer (score 1):

**Surely this would work:**

```
$row = 'SELECT * FROM admins WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1';
if(!empty($row) header('Location: /admins');

$row = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1';
if(!empty($row)) header('Location: /users');
```

Obviously you can't just pick-up and drop this code in, but the logistics of how it would work are there, for example I'm not sure how you're connecting to a database so I don't want to pre-write code that isn't useful in your situation.